# Internal and External memory fragmentation

Tags: operating-system

I am currently reading OS and read about internal and external memory fragmentation.

**Internal fragmentation** is based on fixed size partitioning. For example = paging is based on fixed size partitioning and hence, paging suffers from internal fragmentation.

On the other hand, **External fragmentation** is based on variable size partitioning.
For example = segmentation is based on dynamic variable size partitioning and hence, segmentation suffers from external fragmentation.

**So, my doubt is there is internal fragmentation in paging, so it has 0 external fragmentation or there is something very small, so we can neglect that
and

Similarly, for segmentation, does it also has 0 internal fragmentation or very small, that can be neglected?**

Is my understanding right ?

Comment: Paging may have very small fraction of internal fragmentation, since the the last frame allocated may not be utilized 100%, so internal fragmentation at most is in proportion to that of page size.

Comment: So, the last page is internally fragmented ?

Answer (score 2):

Internal fragmentation is sujected to "Fixed size partitioning scheme" and external fragmentation to "variable size partitioning ".
No, there can never be external fragementation in fixed size partitioning because the leftover space cannot be used to allocate to any other process. External fragmentation occurs only when "there is space available which can be allocated to the process but due to non availability of enough contiguous space,the available space cannot be allocated".
On the other hand,in case of variable size partitioning, there can never be internal fragmentation because the lefover space can be allocated to the process of same or less than the available space(though the probability of allotment could be very less).
We can remove internal fragmentation and external fragmentation, if we can use a method "non-contiguous allocation" in "variable size partitioning".